# Why does my Transmission client tell me my tracker list contains invalid URLs?

Tags: internet, file-sharing, downloads, transmission, bittorrent

When I type in custom trackers into the tracker list, and try to save the list I get a message saying:

*List contains invalid URLs*

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the first link hat I found on google... after trying about a dozen from a list i found online I realized why I was getting this message. Windows uses a carriage return and newline to denote an end of line, where unix only uses a newline. I opened the file in my IDE (geany) and converted the line endings and it worked for the entire list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi pfifo! I will give this a try soon as I can! Thank you!

Comment: I just read that list in python and inserted '\n\n' on every list element, Solved my problem for transmission in ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it includes udp trackers, which aren't supported in Transmission until version 2.30.

Comment: They are HTTP though, does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, trackers (in my case) had to be added one by one. Adding them all at once would cause that error message.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was solved by using [udp trackers](http://www.dsfc.net/internet/liste-de-trackers-torrent-udp/) and leaving a blank line after each link.

Comment: The add button adds one link at a time. I used edit. which opens something like a text file where multiple trackers can be added at once.

Answer (score 0):

Issue may be because of certain characters in the list. Open sublime text and copy the list you want to add.

Then use <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> and replace **\s\s** (assuming lines are separated by one empty line) with **\n** (use Regular Expession option) and try pasting. It worked for me. Initially i tried copying one 1 line and noticed some control character was being inserted (may be true in your case too. Use the 'Add' button in transmission to verify)